# React Native function not triggering

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, react-redux

So, I have this component,

```
{ this.props.isConfirmModalOpen && shiftInvite && <ConfirmApplicationPopUp
  memberPhoto={props.memberProfile && props.memberProfile.photo}
  venueLogo={getOr('noop', 'account.logo', shiftInvite)}
  isOpen={props.isConfirmModalOpen}
  shift={shiftInvite}
  isOnboarding={isOnboardingMember}
  onClose={props.onToggleConfirmPopUp}
  onConfirm={this.handleConfirmApplication}
  checkValues={props.confirmationCheckValues}
  onUpdateCheckValues={props.onUpdateConfirmationCheckValues}
  isHomeComponent
/> }
```

As you can see, I pass on onConfirm the handleConfirmApplication function, which is a check for some stuff and has to run a function in the try block, , here's the function

```
handleConfirmApplication = async () => {
    const checkVals =
      get('shift.account.accountName', this.props) === ONBOARDING_ACCOUNT
        ? omit('payRate', this.props.confirmationCheckValues)
        : this.props.confirmationCheckValues;
    if (Object.values(checkVals).every(val => val)) {
      this.props.onToggleConfirmPopUp();
      this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
      try {
        console.log('inTry1');
        await this.handleShiftInviteDecision('ACCEPT');
        console.log('inTry2');
      } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert('Error', parseError(e));
      } finally {
        this.props.onToggleLoadingApply();
        console.log('inFinally');
      }
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please confirm all shift requirements');
    }
  };
```

My problem is, for whatever reason, it doesn't run the handleShiftInviteDecision('ACCEPT) for whatever reason, i'm awaiting it, tried to put it in another function, call them both from another function ETC, the function does not run!
Here's the handleShiftInviteDecision function too

```
  handleShiftInviteDecision = (decision: 'ACCEPT' | 'DECLINE') => async () => {
    console.log('handleSIDecision1');
    const [shiftInvite] = getOr([], 'shiftInvites', this.state.modals);
    console.log('handleSIDecision2');
    if (decision === 'ACCEPT') {
      analytics.hit(new PageHit(`ShiftInviteModal-ACCEPT-${shiftInvite.id}`));
      console.log('handleSIDecision3');
    } else if (decision === 'DECLINE') {
      analytics.hit(new PageHit(`ShiftInviteModal-DECLINE-${shiftInvite.id}`));
      console.log('handleSIDecision4');
    }
    try {
      console.log("thisSHouldRun")
      this.setState({ isLoading: true, display: false });
      await this.props.updateMyApplication(shiftInvite.id, decision);
      console.log('handleSIDecision5');
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert('Error', parseError(e));
    } finally {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false, display: false });
    }
  };
```

Any ideeas on what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `handleShiftInviteDecision` is a function that returns an `async` function.

```
handleShiftInviteDecision = (decision: 'ACCEPT' | 'DECLINE') => async () => {
```

So, you would need to call the `async` function it returns to invoke it:

```
  try {
    console.log('inTry1');
    await this.handleShiftInviteDecision('ACCEPT')();  // <--- here
    console.log('inTry2');
  } catch (e) {
```